# In Flex , test a array containg a certain value in flex

Tags: arrays, apache-flex

I have an array which has many values in it . I just wanted a simple and good approach check whether the array contains a particular value. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Array.indexOf()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) like this:

```
if (myArray.indexOf(item) != -1) trace("item exists");
else trace("nope! can't find it")
```

indexOf returns the index if the item exists, or -1 if it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(myArray.indexOf("<searchObject>") < 0) //Code here (returns -1 if the value isn't found) 
{ 
    //the value isn't found
} else
{ 
    //the value is found
}
```

Comment: This is extremely weird. You asked the question. RIAstar answered it. Then you thought it appropriate to make unnecessary changes to his answer, and answer the question yourself instead of accepting his answer?!